# hibernate + маппинг без сущностей?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Я разбираю старый проект и нашел интересную вещь, которую не понимаю

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <subclass entity-name="NameClassEntity" extends="DefaultedNameClassEntity" discriminator-value="376">
        <meta attribute="main" inherit="true">dt</meta>

        <meta attribute="control" inherit="true">com.class.NameClassEntityC</meta>
        <meta attribute="control" inherit="true">com.class.QuantityNameClassEntityControl</meta>
```

Для этого файла в котором описываются правила для маппинга, нет класса-сущности (java класса).

Кроме того, ссылки на файлы с такими правилами (а это более 900 Xml-файлов), описаны в специальном файле **hibernate.cfg.xml**

```java
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping resource="com/NameClassEntity.hbm.xml"/>
…
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

кроме того, вот эта часть,

```java
 discriminator-value="376"
```

указывает на то, что используется стратегия **Hibernate**:

- **a single table per class hierarchy** — все **enity**, со всеми классами наследниками, записываются в одну и туже таблицу, а для идентификации конкретного  типа **entity**  - определяется специальная колонка **discriminator** column.

  Прав ли я ?

И никто из коллег не смог объяснить, как это работает ???

В один из таких **xml**, было добавлено поле, но оно не появилось после пересборки проекта (проект обычный, Tomcat + Java2EE, без Maven) в приложении ?...

Но ведь для того, чтобы это правило работало, оно должно иметь некоторую сущность описанную в Java-классе.
 И коллега утверждает, что  так работает **без соответствующего класса-сущности**(правда среда разработки уже Eclipse, но не intellij idea)

Кстати, Hibernate-библиотека, очень старая и была модифицирована разработчиками
приложения, которое теперь приходится разворачивать в среде intellij Idea.

Приложение запускается, но вот поле описанное в xml, не появилось в клиентской части, при запросе, таблицы, к которой и было описано в xml, добавляемое поле..

**Обновление**

Данный xml, расширяет

```java
extends="DefaultedNameClassEntity"
```

**NameClassEntity** - класс с таким именем отсутствует

затем

```java
<joined-subclass entity-name="DefaultedNameClassEntity" table="DTTable" extends="Instance"
                     discriminator-value="374" defaulted="true">
```

DefaultedNameClassEntity - класс с таким именем не найден

**extends="Instance"**

```java
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <class entity-name="Instance" table="Instance" abstract="true" discriminator-value="2">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="long" >
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <discriminator column="class" type="long" insert="true" not-null="true" />

        <property name="nick" type="string" length="32" not-null="false">
            <meta attribute="description"><![CDATA[ID Пользователя]]></meta>
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Instance - найден интерфейс с таким именем в одном из проектов (все приложение состоит из 17 проектов в одном Workspace)

```java
public interface Instance extends Configurable<Instance> {
  Long id();

  /**
   * Returns type that based on configured product information.
   */
  Type getType();

  /**
   * Saves the instance.
   */
  void store();

  /**
   * Deletes the instance.
   */
  void delete();

  /**
   * Get a value of the configurable object or returns null if there is not
   * appropriate attribute.
   */
  <V> Value<V> getValue(Attribute<V> attribute);

  Value[] getValues();

  Instance getParent();


}
```

У кого есть какие идеи, может мне пояснить, как вообще может **hibernate** работать без класса-сущности ... ?

Comment: Возможно это вложенный класс. Попробуйте поискать все вхождения в проект по имени NameClassEntity

Comment: я думаю классы недостающих сущностей генерирует сам hibernate. В xml указана схема наследования и этого достаточно. Вроде логично. Что вас так смутило?

Comment: я всегда считал и так работаю (если используется Spirng Boot или Spring), ну и вообще, что для того, чтобы hibernate смог сопоставить какую-то таблицу с java-объектом, тогда мы должны были бы описать данный java-объект. Если вы знаете другой подход (другое использование hibernate), тогда где это описано ?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate поддерживает динамические модели. То есть в данном случае ему не нужен класс. Он использует Maps of Maps во время выполнения

Фрагмент из документации hibernate 4.2 (Dynamic models):

> Persistent entities do not necessarily have to be represented as POJO
>   classes or as JavaBean objects at runtime. Hibernate also supports
>   dynamic models (using Maps of Maps at runtime). With this approach,
>   you do not write persistent classes, only mapping files.

```
<hibernate-mapping>

    <class entity-name="Customer">

        <id name="id"
            type="long"
            column="ID">
            <generator class="sequence"/>
        </id>

        <property name="name"
            column="NAME"
            type="string"/>

        <many-to-one name="organization"
            column="ORGANIZATION_ID"
            class="Organization"/>

        <bag name="orders"
            inverse="true"
            lazy="false"
            cascade="all">
            <key column="CUSTOMER_ID"/>
            <one-to-many class="Order"/>
        </bag>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Ваш случай отличается тем, что за основу берется POJO класс-родитель. Как реализовано смешивание двух подходов: через карты карт и POJO - вопрос более глубокого погружения.